# image over flow on header while scrolling

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have an Html page with certain images. While scrolling, all images overflow on the header. I set the header to `position: fixed`, and if I remove `position:relative` its works fine, but the image looses its alignment.

```
<div class="show-image">
    <img src="images/colourise.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
    <div style="margin-left:50px;">
        <a href="images/colourise.jpg"><input class="update" type="button" value="View" id="mybutton1"/></a>
    </div>
    <p class="sme">Colorise</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.show-image {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    padding:28px;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give header `z-index` higher than images.

Comment: Can you create a full fiddle? Seems the solution is very easy just need to understand the issue

Comment: As I have told the issue is in z-index. Updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/frontDev111/Lnj1oobt/2/ . Result with printscreen too http://gyazo.com/e82588e6dc908f01253329f6c3aebe14